# How do i fix ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python, python-3.x

WHy doesnt this code solve x1 for a quadratic function

## solution for quadratic equation

## a*x**2 + b*x + c = 0

```
import math

def fn(a,b,c):
    return (-b+math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2*a

print(fn(34,68,510))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The roots of that quadratic (34x^2 + 68x + 510) are complex. `math.sqrt` is real-valued -- it won't take a negative value. You'll need `import cmath` and `cmath.sqrt` to do a complex-valued square root.

Comment: Thank you for the help @a spaghetto . I am new to python thank you for the clarification. If you could please up vote the question it would be greatly appreciated